No converter found capable of converting [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap
I have the following Entity:
@Entity
@Table(name = "signing_keys")
@Getter
@Setter
public class SigningKeysEnt {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "encrypted_private_key")
    private String encryptedPrivateKey;

    @Column(name = "public_key")
    private String publicKey;

    @Column(name = "protocol_version")
    private String protocolVersion;

    @Column(name = "signature_algorithm")
    private String signatureAlgorithm;

    @Column(name = "expiration_date")
    private Date expirationDate;


}

JPA Repository:
@Repository
public interface SigningKeysRepository extends JpaRepository<SigningKeysEnt, Long> {

  @Query(value = """
                    SELECT public_key AS publicKey,
                          protocol_version AS protocolVersion,
                          expiration_date AS expirationDate
                    FROM signing_keys                                               
            """, nativeQuery = true)
  List<SigningKey> getPublicKeys();
}

DAO which I need to return:
public class SigningKey {

  private String publicKey;
  private String protocolVersion;
  private Date expirationDate;

  // getter/setter
}

I need to return List<SigningKey> but I get: Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type [com.SigningKey]
I tried to use Class-Based Projections by adding constructor into SigningKey DAO like this:
public class SigningKey {

  private String publicKey;
  private String protocolVersion;
  private Date expirationDate;

  public SigningKey() {
  }

  public SigningKey(String publicKey, String protocolVersion, Date expirationDate) {
    this.publicKey = publicKey;
    this.protocolVersion = protocolVersion;
    this.expirationDate = expirationDate;
  }
  /// getter/setter
}

But still I get the same error.
Are there other ways to fix the issue? I need to use Class-Based Projections in order to avoid code refactoring.

Why aren't yyou just using the findAll and convert yourself? If you want to use a projection you need JPQL not SQL. something like SELECT new SigningKey(s.publicKey, s.protocolVersion, s.expirationDate) FROM SigningKeysEnt s as the JPQL. This will only select the columns you need and return what you want.

yes it's also a solution but I have many native queries. Do you know where I'm wrong in my Class-Based Projection solution?

From your question it suggest you just added this. Either way you need to explictly do some mapping or write a JPQL, so one way or another there are going to be changes.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/repositories/projections.html#projections.dtos

From the link above: "it’s important to point out that class-based projections do not work with native queries AT ALL"

ok, noted. What about Dynamic Projections?  https://maciejwalkowiak.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-dynamic-projections/#:~:text=Projection%20is%20a%20subset%20of,projections%20used%20in%20the%20application.

Can it be not native query?
Something like:
 @Query(value = "SELECT new your.package.SigningKey(sk.publicKey, sk.protocolVersion, sk.expirationDate " +
                "FROM signing_keys sk")
  List<SigningKey> getPublicKeys();

